# ¿Como creo una condicion IF en caso de que mi insercion de datos en la base de datos sea incorrecta?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy elaborando una insercion de datos de un formalario meiante php a una base de datos (mysql), Yo quiero que el codigo me avise o muestre un mensaje de error en 'echo' en caso de que la variable de consulta $Resultado arroje un error.

CODIGO PHP-HTML

```
    <?php
        $con=mysqli_connect ('127.0.0.1','root','','freatico') or die ('ERROR EN LA CONEXION A LA BASE DE DATOS');
        $sql="INSERT INTO puntos VALUES ('".$_POST['idp']."','".$_POST['locali']."','".$_POST['ultmed']."','".$_POST['vref']."','".$_POST['altubo']."','".$_POST['sms']."')";
        $resultado=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ('ERROR EN EL QUERY DATABASE');
        if($resultado){
            if( mysqli_num_rows( $resultado )<=0){

                echo 'EL PUNTO QUE ACABA DE REGISTRAR YA EXISTE';
        }
    }
        mysqli_close ($con);
    ?>
```

Les agradezo si me ayudan a reconstruir mi codigo de forma que se pueda hacer lo que necesito.

Comment: Prueba de esta forma `if($resultado){ echo "Se guardo el registro en la Base de Datos"; } else { printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con)); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la función `mysqli_num_rows` regresa el conteo de registros de un SELECT, tu estas haciendo un INSERT, para comprobar si tu registro fue insertado puedes usar `mysqli_affected_rows` este te dice si el registro fue insertado y también sirve para hacer UPDATES. Si tienes tus puntos con un campo AUTOINCREMENT puedes regresar el ID del nuevo registro con `mysqli_insert_id`

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect ('127.0.0.1','root','','freatico') or die ('ERROR EN LA CONEXION A LA BASE DE DATOS');
    $sql="INSERT INTO puntos VALUES ('".$_POST['idp']."','".$_POST['locali']."','".$_POST['ultmed']."','".$_POST['vref']."','".$_POST['altubo']."','".$_POST['sms']."')";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ('ERROR EN EL QUERY DATABASE');
    if($resultado){
        if( mysqli_affected_rows($con) <= 0){
            echo 'EL PUNTO QUE ACABA DE REGISTRAR YA EXISTE';
    }

    else{
      echo mysqli_insert_id($con);
    }
}
    mysqli_close ($con);
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda amigo. Le modifique algunas cosas pero me sirvio tu explicacion.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer esto.

```
<?php
        $con=mysqli_connect ('127.0.0.1','root','','freatico') or die ('ERROR EN LA CONEXION A LA BASE DE DATOS');
        $sql="INSERT INTO puntos VALUES ('".$_POST['idp']."','".$_POST['locali']."','".$_POST['ultmed']."','".$_POST['vref']."','".$_POST['altubo']."','".$_POST['sms']."')";
        $resultado=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ('ERROR EN EL QUERY DATABASE');
        if($resultado){
            if( mysqli_num_rows( $resultado )<=0){

                echo 'EL PUNTO QUE ACABA DE REGISTRAR YA EXISTE';
        }
    }
else {

echo"<script>alert('Error al insertar los datos')</script>";

}

        mysqli_close ($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: La respuesta parece correcta, te recomendaria que añadas información indicando que has añadido y por qué. Las respuestas que muestran solo codigo y no tienen una explicacion se consideran de baja calidad